# JavaScript confirm() doesn't work when using the variant of Safari that's embedded inside iOS apps (e.g. when a user clicks a link in FB Messenger)?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, wkwebview

Users using Safari on iOS on my site experience no issues, if they've manually navigated to the site using Safari.

If, however, someone has sent them a link and they've clicked it, the pseudo browser that opens up (what is the proper name for this please - is it WKWebView?) breaks the site. Most things work fine, but if my site throws up a `confirm()` dialogue, nothing happens - it doesn't pop up, and the user gets no feedback that anything has gone wrong, other than their expected action didn't occur.

I'm unclear if the pseudo-browser is unable to show it, or is "displaying" it erroneously outside of the viewport somewhere.

Both in native Safari and in the in-app Safari I get a loading animation of 5 dots/bars moving left to right next to the wifi symbol at the top of the phone. In Safari that goes when I close the confirm, in pseudo Safari there's no confirm to close, and that animation is perpetual.

How should I fix this?

When searching for the issue I find plenty of advice for people making iOS apps telling them how to allow `confirm()``alert()`\`prompt()`in their in-app browser, but I can't find any Q&A aimed at webmasters like myself, on how to address the fact that our sites don't work in these browsers.  Is the only option to get rid of the`confirm()` and generate an html/css popup of my own making?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Hey it's a confirm box code with JS and CSS.

```
function confirm(question) {
    return new Promise(r => {
        const behind = document.createElement("div");
        behind.style = `
position:fixed;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
left:0;
top:0;
z-index: 99999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
`
        document.body.append(behind)
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.style = `
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
`
        const q = document.createElement("span");
        q.style = `
color:white;
font-size:5em;
`
        q.innerText = question;
        container.append(q)
        const ync = document.createElement("div"); //yes no container
        ync.style =
            `
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
display:flex;
`
        var btn = document.createElement("span");
        btn.innerText = "Yes";
        btn.style = `
cursor:pointer;
color:white;
background:#2ebf91;
text-align:center;
padding:8% 30%;
font-size:5em;
`
        btn.onclick = function() {
            r(true);
            behind.remove();
        }
        ync.append(btn)
        btn = btn.cloneNode();
        btn.onclick = function() {
            r(false);
            behind.remove();
        }
        btn.style.background = "#ec2F4B"
        btn.innerText = "No";
        btn.style.marginLeft = "20%"
        ync.append(btn)
        container.append(ync)
        behind.append(container)
    })
}
```

You can change CSS or include it in style / html, I'm not an expert at CSS.

So maybe bad design.

## Usage

```
console.log(await confirm("test")); // wait until click button
```